# What is the name of rank $n$ where these primes occurs

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $(p_{n})$ be the sequences of primes. We know that the quantity $g_{n}=p_{n+1}-p_{n}$ is called **gap**.
Consider the case of twin primes $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=2$.

My **question** is:

What is the name of rank $n$ where these primes occurs. For example, $n=2,3,...$.

Comment: You're asking about the values of $n$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n=2$? If the twin prime conjecture is true, then there are infinitely many such $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I am asking about the name of those $n$.

Comment: Yes, but you have written that "If the twin prime conjecture is true, then this number is still finite." That's not right, is it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes. Edited.

Comment: OK. Now, why would such $n$ have a name? The numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A029707 but no name is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term, for the numerical subscript when used in mathematics related to sets, is an index. Its used as reference to the ordering of the elements of the ordered set (or a sequence more likely). For example if my set were $\{2x:x\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (aka the even numbers) then then $x$ acts as an index and arguably could be referred to for the $x$*th* even number by using notation as $2_x$, however dangerous (definition might be required at that point though).

Another way subscripts are used in mathematics,and computing, is for bases. A numerical string, could be $123_3$ for $1\cdot 3^2 +2\cdot 3+3$ for example.

You can index in two dimensions as well, like binomial coefficients in pascal's triangle, or rows and columns of a matrix. It just takes two reference points though, usually using a hanging subscript or a comma in a subscript $_nC_r$ (sometimes written $^nC_r$) and $H_{n,m}$ for example.

**EDIT** we could call them the set of numbers that aren't of form $2ab+a+b$, because $2(2ab+a+b)+1 = (2a+1)(2b+1)$ which makes it composite if $a,b>0$ via Sieve of Sundaram., okay thinking wrong way, it's just an index on the primes which are a set of numbers set out as above.